# Removing a row from a csv file when it is selected from a comboBox and a button pressed

Tags: c#, csv, row

I recently asked about a piece of code to hold data for my trading cards. I have a file that contains the overall list of the cards in a CSV file. I was wondering if there was any way to remove a row from the CSV file when the card number is selected and the submit button pressed. The code I currently have is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace YuGiOh_Card_List
{
    public partial class frmAddLOB : Form
    {
        List<string> cardNo = new List<string>();
        List<string> cardName = new List<string>();
        List<string> cardRarity = new List<string>();
        List<string> cardType = new List<string>();

        public frmAddLOB()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("..\\Debug\\lobList.csv");

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');

            cardNo.Add(values[0]);
            cardName.Add(values[1]);
            cardRarity.Add(values[2]);
            cardType.Add(values[3]);

            cboCardNo.Items.Add(values[0]);
        }

        reader.Close();
    }

    private void cboCardNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblCardNoFinal.Text = cardNo[cboCardNo.SelectedIndex];
        lblCardNameFinal.Text = cardName[cboCardNo.SelectedIndex];
        lblCardRarityFinal.Text = cardRarity[cboCardNo.SelectedIndex];
        lblCardTypeFinal.Text = cardType[cboCardNo.SelectedIndex];
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string file = ("..\\Debug\\LOB.csv");
        string delimiter = ",";            

        var card = new Card(lblCardNoFinal.Text, lblCardNameFinal.Text, lblCardRarityFinal.Text, lblCardTypeFinal.Text);
        Global.card.Add(card);
        File.AppendAllLines(file, new[] { card.CardNo + delimiter + card.CardName + delimiter + card.CardRarity + delimiter + card.CardType });

        MessageBox.Show("Card Added");            
    }
}
```

}

So I want the row to be removed from the 'loblist.csv' and added to the LOB file (which it is currently doing). Thanks

Comment: rather than parallel collection representing certain aspects of each card, it would be easier (and less error prone) to create a Card class then one collection.  Saving could be 2-3 lines of serialization or looping to write whatever is in the collection

Comment: Are all the lines in the source file unique?

Comment: Yeah all lines are unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (untested). Unfortunately, there's no classes/methods available in .Net (AFAIK) for in-place editing of text files (it makes sense when you think about it I guess). Disclaimer - there are much cleaner ways to do what you're aiming for here functionality-wise, including the approach described by Plutonix above:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace YuGiOh_Card_List
{
    public partial class frmAddLOB : Form
    {
        List<string> cardNo = new List<string>();
        List<string> cardName = new List<string>();
        List<string> cardRarity = new List<string>();
        List<string> cardType = new List<string>();
       List<string> Lines = new List<string>();

        public frmAddLOB()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("..\\Debug\\lobList.csv");

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();

                var values = line.Split(',');

                Lines.Add(line);
                cardNo.Add(values[0]);
                cardName.Add(values[1]);
                cardRarity.Add(values[2]);
                cardType.Add(values[3]);

                cboCardNo.Items.Add(values[0]);
            }

            reader.Close();
        }

        private void cboCardNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblCardNoFinal.Text = cardNo[cboCardNo.SelectedIndex];
            lblCardNameFinal.Text = cardName[cboCardNo.SelectedIndex];
            lblCardRarityFinal.Text = cardRarity[cboCardNo.SelectedIndex];
            lblCardTypeFinal.Text = cardType[cboCardNo.SelectedIndex];
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string file = ("..\\Debug\\LOB.csv");
            string delimiter = ",";

            var card = new Card(lblCardNoFinal.Text, lblCardNameFinal.Text, lblCardRarityFinal.Text,
                lblCardTypeFinal.Text);
            Global.card.Add(card);
            var newLine = card.CardNo + delimiter + card.CardName + delimiter + card.CardRarity + delimiter +
                          card.CardType;
            File.AppendAllLines(file,
                new string [] {newLine});

            if (Lines.Contains(newLine))
            {
                Lines.Remove(newLine);
                File.WriteAllLines("..\\Debug\\lobList.csv", Lines);
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Card Added");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that works perfect, thanks a lot! I always find myself getting confused on the simplest things haha. Thanks again :)